# Counting a particular variable in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this following Array. Here, i want to count the variable `fraction` which has the value 1. Based on the no.of.occurances, i want to do some operations. The one way i know is, to loop the array by using `foreach` and put an incrementor to identify how many `fraction` has the value 1. But i want to know is there any easier way than the above one?

could anyone suggest me?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [answer] => <p>
    Quiz Test Interoperability</p>

            [feedback] => 
            [fraction] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [answer] => <p>
    Quiz Test Interrelationship</p>

            [feedback] => <br />

            [fraction] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [answer] => <p>
    Quiz Team Interoperability</p>

            [feedback] => <br />

            [fraction] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [answer] => <p>
    Queation Test Interoperability</p>

            [feedback] => <br />

            [fraction] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_reduce()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php
function countFractionIs1 ($element) {
   return ($element['fraction'] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
}

$count = array_reduce($yourarray, "countFractionIs1", 0);
```